# Printing values in special format using printf

Tags: linux, shell, printf

I need to print the following values with printf as the follwoing around like this:

```
printf "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`] [WARN] $PARAM1 $PARAM2 $PARAM3
```

The required output:

```
[02/Jun/2010-11:08:42] [WARN]  val1....val2...val3
```

the gap between val1 to val2 and from val2 to val3 must be const gap 
not depend the length of the values

Comment: This looks more like BASH than C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf "%s [WARN] %s %s %s\n" `date +"%d/%b/%G-%T"` foo bar baz
```

Not sure what you meant by constant gap. If it is a column width for `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, try `%13s`, where 13 is minimum column width.

Comment: waht about the new line in the printf sytax?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question.
Using another answer as a base for mine:

If you want to pad each of the PARAMs then just add a numerical argument to the printf and it will pad it out to that number of characters per field.

Pad by 20 characters:
    printf "%s [WARN] %20s %20s %20s" `date +"%d/%b/%G-%T"` foo bar baz

Examples:

```
printf "%s [WARN] %16s %16s %16s" [`date +"%d/%b/%G-%T"`] foo bar baz

02/Jun/2010-11:22:54 [WARN]              foo              bar              baz
```

Longer...

```
printf "%s [WARN] %16s %16s %16s" [`date +"%d/%b/%G-%T"`] longerfoo longerbar longerbaz

02/Jun/2010-11:23:42 [WARN]        longerfoo        longerbar        longerbaz
```

Much Longer...

```
printf "%s [WARN] %16s %16s %16s" [`date +"%d/%b/%G-%T"`] muchlongerfoo muchlongerbar muchlongerbaz

02/Jun/2010-11:24:12 [WARN]    muchlongerfoo    muchlongerbar    muchlongerbaz
```

Try it on a console. It works.

Comment: Looks like hudolejev added the bit about column width while I was writing this one... You have two identical answers for the price of one! Woohoo!

Comment: hi again according to your example I get the follwoing , but the upper PARAM word not on the same side of the lower PARAM? 


[WARN]    PARAM=oooee FILE=xxx MACHINE_NAME=uuu 
[WARN] PARAM=pppp FILE=lll MACHINE_NAME=ttt

Comment: @yael that's because strings get right-justified by default. To get them left-justified, use `"%-16s"`.