# Print equal-width columns in C using printf formatting

Tags: c, printf

I would like to print columns using printf in C. I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printme(char *txt1, char *txt2, char *txt3)
{
    printf("TXT1: %9s TXT2 %9s TXT3 %9s\n", txt1, txt2, txt3);
}


int main()
{
    printme("a","bbbbbbbeeeeebbbbb","e");
    printme("aaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbb","abcde");
    return 0;
}
```

It works but I have such output:

```
TXT1:         a TXT2 bbbbbbbeeeeebbbbb TXT3         e
TXT1:  aaaaaaaa TXT2 bbbbbbbbbbbb TXT3     abcde
```

So the columns are not equal-width. Basicly, I would like to make it like this, that no matter how long is text in my argument, my function would ALWAYS print out a nice formatted columns. The question is: how can I do this?

By saing *nice* I meant that no matter how long text I pass to my printing function, it will always print out equal-width columns, for example:

I have this output that looks like this:

```
a         cd`           fg           ij  
a         cd             fg           ij  
a         cd             fg           ij  
ab         cd             fg           ij  
ab         cd             fg           i j   
ab         cd             fg           ij  
ab         cd             fg           ij  
ab         cde             fgh         ij  
ab         cde             fgh         ij
```

I want it to look like this (no matter how long my text arguments will be):

```
a         cd`           fg           ij  
a         cd            fg           ij  
a         cd            fg           ij  
ab        cd            fg           ij  
ab        cd            fg           ij   
ab        cd            fg           ij  
ab        cd            fg           ij  
ab        cde           fgh          ij  
ab        cde           fgh          ij
```

Comment: Define *nice* in *nice formatted columns*.

Comment: so scan your text in advance, figure out what the longest string is, and use that length for your column padding values.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956296/printing-values-in-special-format-using-printf

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838388/how-to-format-printf-statement-better-so-things-always-line-up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the maximum length for `txt1`, `txt2`, and `txt3`, and then format it:

```
// compute the max string length of txt1 inputs in advance
int s1 = strlen(firstTxt1);
if (s1 < strlen(secondTxt1)
    s1 = strlen(secondTxt1);
...

printf("%.*s %.*s %.*s\n", s1, txt1, s2, txt2, s3, txt3);
```

Comment: What happens if you have continuous output (e.g. continuously printing information into a table-like structure) and suddenly the data for one column is longer than all its predecessors (the the column needs to be made wider)? I know of `\b` and `\r` but they don't really solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe it's my compiler, but why doesn't this method work for me? `printf("%.*s",5,"hi");` just prints "hi" as if the length wasn't specified but `%5s` works fine. Do you have any links that explain specifically this in detail? I'm assuming the Google search term would be "formatting in printf"?

Answer (score 13):

If you want the strings to be truncated if they're larger than the column width, then you can just add a precision for the string format specification:

```
printf("TXT1: %9.9s TXT2 %9.9s TXT3 %9.9s\n", txt1, txt2, txt3);
```

With that `printf()`, the output of your example program looks like:

```
TXT1:         a TXT2 bbbbbbbee TXT3         e
TXT1:  aaaaaaaa TXT2 bbbbbbbbb TXT3     abcde
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at my simple library, [libtprint](https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint): https://github.com/wizzard/libtprint 
The code is pretty simple, you should be able to understand how it works.

Basically what you need is to play with the fields widths for each column and calculate alignment offsets.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no TRIVIAL method for doing this.

You could do a two-pass method - in main():

```
char **data[] = { { "a","bbbbbbbeeeeebbbbb","e" }, 
                  {"aaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbb","abcde" } };


get_columwidths(data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2]); 
get_columwidths(data[1][0], data[1][1], data[1][2]); 

printme(data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2]); 
printme(data[1][0], data[1][1], data[1][2]);
```

and then this:

```
int columnwidths[3];

void get_columwidths(const char *s1, const char *s2, const char *s3)
{
    int len1 = strlen(s1); 
    int len2 = strlen(s2); 
    int len3 = strlen(s3); 

    if (columnwidths[0] < len1) columnwidths[0] = len1;
    if (columnwidths[1] < len2) columnwidths[1] = len2;
    if (columnwidths[2] < len3) columnwidths[2] = len3;
}

void printme(char *txt1, char *txt2, char *txt3)
{
    printf("TXT1: %*s TXT2 %*s TXT3 %*s\n", 
           columnwidths[0], txt1, columnwidths[1], txt2, columnwidths[2], txt3);
}
```

Comment: +1 because using `%*s` instead of `%.*s` (note the period) like in the accepted answer this method does _not_ print leading zeros when printing integers (`%*d`).