# How to format a printf statement to column name

Tags: c, format, printf

Not all the output line up with "column3". Is there a special way to subtract the spaces where certain numbers do not line up? Do I need to create separate printf statements, maybe?

With my below(horrible looking) printf statement

```
 printf("%d \t%lf \t\t%lf \t%lf    %lf \n", i, row1[i], row2[i], row3[i], row4[i]);
```

Heres what I get :

```
#   Column          Column1     Column2       Column3 
1   1.400000        32.300000   333.000000    66.500000 
2   11.200000       32.300000   11111.000000    35.900000
3   11.800000       32.300000   23333.000000    2.500000
4   1.500000        2.300000    32.000000    22.500000
5   1.000000        1.000000    333.000000    6.500000
6   11.000000       1.000000    3433.000000    665.500000
```

How can I get it to print:

```
#   Column          Column1     Column2       Column3 
1   1.400000        32.300000   333.000000    66.500000 
2   11.200000       32.300000   11111.000000  35.900000
3   11.800000       32.300000   23333.000000  2.500000
4   1.500000        2.300000    32.000000     22.500000
5   1.000000        1.000000    333.000000    6.500000
6   11.000000       1.000000    3433.000000   665.500000
```

Comment: Look this link maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751826/print-equal-width-columns-in-c-using-printf-formatting

Comment: You could use a tab instead of just spaces between the last two `%lf` conversion specifications.  Personally, I'd rather the numbers were aligned with the decimal points at the same place.  To do that, you'd use something like `%12.3f` (to print with 3 decimal places in a field of 12 characters — 8 digits, dot, 3 digits, or minus sign, 7 digits, dot, 3 digits).  I tend to avoid tabs in output — their interpretation is erratic.  But you can do as you wish.  Change the numbers in the fields to suit your needs.  If you really want left-justified numbers, use `%-12.3f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this

```
printf("%15d\t%15lf\t%15lf\t%15lf\t%15lf\n",
    i, row1[i], row2[i], row3[i], row4[i]);
```