# Applying spaces in C

Tags: c, string

I want to make exactly 12 spaces between 2 strings without entering 12 spaces in C but i don't know how to do it.I have tried putting 12 spaces, but it takes so long.I also used tab but if the string too long it doesnt seems good. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

I have the code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        char a[3]="a";
        char b[3]="b";
        printf("name            job",&a,&b);
        printf("%s %s",&a,&b);
    }
```

result: `a b`
the result I want: `a            b` (12 spaces between a and b)

Comment: `printf("%s%*s%s\n", a, 12, "", b);`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That only works if `b` has exactly one character in it.

Comment: Note that if this for printing something like a table, inserting tabstops is the easiest way to do it (as long as your contents don't grow longer than a tab)

Comment: Or  maybe this `printf("%s%13s", a, b)`. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print equal-width columns in C using printf formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17751826/1563833) or maybe [Set variable text column width in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105890/1563833)

Comment: `printf("%s %s",&a,&b);` ==> The `%s` format specifier expects a `char *`, not a `char (*)[]`. Drop the `&`s.

Comment: As a side note, spending time on making something as old and ugly as console output look pretty is probably a huge waste of time. Better to create a .csv or something and open it in a useful program.

Comment: @Lundin that's just not true. There are plenty of situations where it's much more convenient to have immediately readable console output without having to involve a GUI in between.

Answer (score -2):

Just add \t between your strings. \t is an escape sequence. It is equivalent to tab i.e 4 spaces. So you can just do %s\t\t\t%s in there

Comment: who said that a tab is 4 spaces?